# Problemas al llamar métodos desde otra clase en Java

Tags: java, poo, método

Estoy tratando de realizar una aplicación con Java `3D`, para ello preciso de una clase llamada `Posi` la cual incluye las transformaciones de los objetos, sin embargo, al querer llamarla desde la clase Principal `(SolarSis)` el compilador me dice que no encuentra el método, a pesar de que ambas clases se encuentran en la misma ubicación y estoy creando el objeto de la clase:

```
public class SolarSis { 
public SolarSis(){   
/* inicializa variables*/
    BranchGroup group = new BranchGroup();
    Appearance appsol = new Appearance();
    Appearance appearth = new Appearance();
    Appearance appvenus = new Appearance();
    Appearance appmercury = new Appearance();
    /* Agregar texturas*/
        TextureLoader tex=new TextureLoader("TIERRA.JPG", null);
        appearth.setTexture(tex.getTexture());
        tex=new TextureLoader("SOL.JPG", null);
        appsol.setTexture(tex.getTexture());
        tex=new TextureLoader("VENUS.JPG", null);
        appsol.setTexture(tex.getTexture());
        tex=new TextureLoader("MERCURIO.JPG", null);
        appsol.setTexture(tex.getTexture());
        /*Añadir esferas con radio*/
        Sphere mercury = new Sphere(0.015f, Primitive.GENERATE_NORMALS |Primitive.GENERATE_TEXTURE_COORDS, 32, appmercury);
        Sphere venus = new Sphere(0.035f, Primitive.GENERATE_NORMALS |Primitive.GENERATE_TEXTURE_COORDS, 32, appvenus);
        Sphere earth = new Sphere(0.045f, Primitive.GENERATE_NORMALS |Primitive.GENERATE_TEXTURE_COORDS, 32, appearth);
        Sphere sol = new Sphere(0.35f, Primitive.GENERATE_NORMALS |Primitive.GENERATE_TEXTURE_COORDS, 32, appsol);
        /*Rotación de los objetos*/
        TransformGroup mercuryRotXformGroup = posi.rotate(mercury, new Alpha(-1, 1750));
        TransformGroup venusRotXformGroup = posi.rotate(venus, new Alpha(-1, 1550));
        TransformGroup earthRotXformGroup = posi.rotate(earth, new Alpha(-1, 1250));
        TransformGroup solRotXformGroup = posi.rotate(sol, new Alpha(-1, 1250));
        /*Traslación de los objetos*/
        TransformGroup mercuryTransXformGroup = posi.translate(mercuryRotXformGroup,new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.1f));
        TransformGroup mercuryRotGroupXformGroup = posi.rotate(mercuryTransXformGroup, new Alpha(-1, 2000));
        TransformGroup venusTransXformGroup = posi.translate(venusRotXformGroup,new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.3f));
        TransformGroup venusRotGroupXformGroup = posi.rotate(venusTransXformGroup, new Alpha(-1, 3000));
        TransformGroup earthTransXformGroup = posi.translate(earthRotXformGroup,new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.7f));
        TransformGroup earthRotGroupXformGroup = posi.rotate(earthTransXformGroup, new Alpha(-1, 5000));
        /*Añadimos las animaciones*/
        group.addChild(earthRotGroupXformGroup);
        group.addChild(venusRotGroupXformGroup);
        group.addChild(mercuryRotGroupXformGroup);
        group.addChild(solRotXformGroup);
        //Añade los recursos gráficos
        GraphicsConfiguration config = SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();
        Canvas3D canvas = new Canvas3D(config); 
        canvas.setSize(400, 400);
        SimpleUniverse universe = new SimpleUniverse(canvas);
        universe.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
        universe.addBranchGraph(group);  
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Planetario");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
        f.add(canvas); 
        f.pack(); 
        f.setVisible(true); 
    }
public static void main(String a[]) { 
    Posi posi = new Posi();
    new SolarSis();}
}
```

Al compilar la clase principal me marca este error en cada parte donde llame algún método de la otra clase:

> SolarSis.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
>                           TransformGroup earthRotGroupXformGroup = posi.rotate(earthTransXformGroup, new Alpha(-1, 5000));
>
> ```
>   symbol:   variable posi
>   location: class SolarSis
> ```

Este es el código de la clase `Posi`:

```
public class Posi {
public static TransformGroup rotate(Node node, Alpha alpha) {
    TransformGroup xformGroup = new TransformGroup();
    xformGroup.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
    RotationInterpolator interpolator =new RotationInterpolator(alpha, xformGroup);
    interpolator.setSchedulingBounds(new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 1.0));
    xformGroup.addChild(interpolator); 
    xformGroup.addChild(node);
    return xformGroup; }
public static TransformGroup translate(Node node, Vector3f vector) {
    Transform3D transform3D = new Transform3D();
    transform3D.setTranslation(vector);
    TransformGroup transformGroup =new TransformGroup(transform3D);
        transformGroup.addChild(node);
    return transformGroup; 
} 
}
```

Si alguien pudiera ayudarme estaría bastante agradecido, no sé si tenga que ver el que esté llamando métodos estáticos, y si fuera el caso, espero que puedan explicarme cómo se deberían de llamar esa clase de métodos.

Comment: ¿Por qué tienes esto en el `Main`?: `Posi posi = new Posi();` debería estar en `public SolarSis(){ `. La variable `posi` no está al alcance ahí. Si por algún motivo debe estar en el `Main` entonces debes modificar el constructor de `SolarSis` para que acepte como parámetro un objeto del tipo `Posi` y pasarlo al crear la instancia de la clase.

Answer (score 2):

> No sé si tenga que ver el que esté llamando métodos estáticos

No, su error no tiene que ver con los métodos estáticos o no de tu clase aunque si mencionar que si los métodos son estáticos no es necesario instanciar la clase para poder acceder a ellos . El error está en el ámbito de la variable `posi` , dentro del método `main` estará disponible pero fuera de este No.

Como son métodos estáticos no es necesario crear la variable en el método `main` y para acceder bastaría con reemplazar todos los `posi` por `Posi` en el  constructor de la clase `SolarSis`

```
TransformGroup earthTransXformGroup = Posi.translate(earthRotXformGroup,new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.7f));
```

El `main` simplemente quedaría

```
public static void main(String a[]) { 
    new SolarSis();}
}
```

> Ojo `Posi` en mayúsculas , el nombre de la clase más no la variable que debería eliminar del método `main`

Comment: Es lo que estaba implementando, pero me dice que no encuentra la variable Posi aún así. :/

Comment: La clase `Posi` , está en el mismo `package` ? si no es así debería importar la clase antes de la clase `SolarSis` de la forma `import packagename.Posi`

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se declara un metodo `static`, este es un metodo de la clase, no del objeto (igual pasa con las variables). Por lo que este metodo solo podra ser accedido por la clase y no por el objeto de esta.

#### Ejemplo

**Clase**

```
public class Clase {

    // Metodo de la clase
    public static void metodoUno() {};

    // Metodo del objeto
    public void metodoDos() {};

}
```

**Clase principal**

```
public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // El metodoUno() solo puede ser accedido 
        // por la clase 
        Clase.metodoUno();

        // El metodoDos() solo puede ser accedido 
        // por el objeto de la clase 
        Clase clase = new Clase();
        clase.metodoDos();

    }

}
```

Los metodos `translate()` y `rotate()` de la clase `Posi` son `static`, por lo que para poder acceder a ellos tienes que utilizar la clase `Posi`.

```
Posi.translate(...);
```

Si quieres acceder a los metodos desde un objeto de la clase `Posi`, tienes que quitarles la palabra reservada `static` para que estos sean metodos del objeto y puedan ser accedidos desde los objetos de la clase `Posi`.

**Clase Posi**

```
public class Posi {

    public TransformGroup translate(Node node, Vector3f vector) {
        Transform3D transform3D = new Transform3D();
        transform3D.setTranslation(vector);
        TransformGroup transformGroup =new TransformGroup(transform3D);
        transformGroup.addChild(node);
        return transformGroup; 
    } 

    ...
}
```

**Objeto Posi**

```
Posi posi = new Posi();
posi.translate(...);
```